# How to Write a Query for the following situation,to fetch the part of the result from more then one table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my Current project I have a feeds menu like facebook.I need to display feeds from tbl_posts ,tbl_events,tbl_shares.I have used ajax pagination on scrolling to load 10 items at a time.therefore i need a single query to load **LATEST FEDDS** from mentioned three tables on scrolling,how to decide the fetched data is event,post or share?

**Ajax scrolling is done as following statements**

consider tbl_post only

1)first i will fetch 10 latest posts from tbl_posts by using limit

2)on scrolling again i will fetch next 10 items and appending to previous posts in ajax.
this is done by single query

But now i have tbl_posts,tbl_events,tbl_shares.therefore i am not getting how to do solve this problem?

Comment: You need 10 latest items which are mixture of three tables?

Comment: yes just 10 latest items from those three tables and i need to identfy  the item is post,share or events.

Comment: Just for final clarification, you execute three queries on three tables, then merge three arrays into one array, and you use that array. Now you problem is that you don't know an item in merged array is post or share?

Comment: No as u suggested is correct if i fetch all rows from three tables at a time and afetr merging is posible to identify the item as event,share or post.

Comment: No as u suggested is correct if i fetch all rows from three tables at a time and afetr merging is posible to identify the item as event,share or post.                                                  Here problem is i am fetching only 10 latest items first and on scroll down i am fetching next 10 items upto end of the rows this procedure continuos.                                                Consider I have a 8 posts on july 2014,5 shares on june 2014 and 20 events on jan 2014.                                                 now how will you fetch latest 10 items

Comment: Ans:in first 10 items->8 posts+2shares                              next 10 items->3 shares+7 events                                         next 10 items->10 events and next 3 events only

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a parent table tbl_feeds of at lease 4 columns: id, feedtype. child table id, timeflag。 such as:   id: 1   feedtype: shares   child table id: 1  timeflag: 2014-7-25。

To display other information of feeds on page depends on the tech you use:
1. put events, shares and posts in cache, load them dynamically when needed
2. save the whole feeds html on the 4th column in parent table
..........

Comment: This is correct and i will accept as answer.but i have a small doubt as bellow.if 1 million users are using my site and they are all busy in posting,sharing and in creation of events.in this condition i need to insert into parent table.i think this table will have more and more load in fraction of seconds right?

Comment: @Paramesh Reddy, to solve your problem: use memory cache for every user, redis, mongodb... are all ok. Suppose there is an user A, you can store A's feeds in a document/key, this could be visited very fast. and then, use message queue or other tech to persist the data to database.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute three queries, and then put the result in an array for each query.

```
$post_result;
$share_result;
$events_result;
```

And then you merge them using array merge;

```
$final_array = array_merge($post_result, $share_result);
$final_array = array_merge($final_array, $events_result);
```

Then you have the following as your final array:

```
$final_array;
```

You could also, while fetching each query into its own array, add an extra field for type:

```
$i = 0;
while($x = $stmt->fetch())
{
   $post_result[$i] = $x;
   $post_result[$i]['type'] = "post";
   $i++;
}
```

Pay attention to $i which I added for extra ability which is clear, being able to assign and manipulate the current index.

Comment: No as u suggested is correct if i fetch all rows from three tables at a time and afetr merging is posible to identify the item as event,share or post. Here problem is i am fetching only 10 latest items first and on scroll down i am fetching next 10 items upto end of the rows this procedure continuos. Consider I have a 8 posts on july 2014,5 shares on june 2014 and 20 events on jan 2014. now how will you fetch latest 10 items

Comment: Ans:in first 10 items->8 posts+2shares                               next 10 items->3 shares+7 events                                    next 10 items->10 events and                                       next 3 events only